# Was it not inexcusably foolish of Sauron to not guard the Ring-destroying lava pit?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, sauron, the-return-of-the-king

I know that he did not think that anyone would want to destroy it, but rather that somebody would instead claim it and try to fight Him with it, but if there is only one place on the planet where the Ring can be destroyed, and the Ring means so much, *and* you are at active war, **and** you hear tidings of "Isildur's bane" ***and*** of Elfish warriors and spies sighted in the heart of Mordor, why not at least appoint one lousy orc or perhaps a couple of Watcher statues that keep everyone away from that place which is the last that Sauron would want anyone to go near if they indeed have the Ring, whether or not they know how to destroy it and have intended for this to happen?

It's possible that it could be destroyed by accident, for example if somebody claims it and then marches toward the Dark Lord's main lair, which, as I understand it, is very close to the Mount Doom.

It seems to me as if Sauron is very foolish in this specific regard, but very calculating and clever in all other ways. I just don't really understand why. Why leave the possibility open? They were two very weak, half-dead hobbits, *and* they also had Gollum lurking around. The slightest guard could have stopped them from ever entering, and even if they didn't, like how the Watchers failed, at least it would have shown that he had thought of this, however unlikely he deemed it.

Comment: I mean, sure, he could have had _more_ guards, but Frodo and Sam had to sneak past at least 2 cordons of guards, not to mention patrols; at some point you have to stop adding guards.

Comment: It's like asking why the Death Star was built with a thermal exhaust port that was vulnerable to close-range pinpoint attack from a small fighter...

Comment: If only he had located it in a closed country behind fortifications staffed by Orcs.

Comment: The TL;DR answer to your question is decidedly  **yes** and Tolkien even says so in the text.

Comment: @N.Petix - "... at least it would have shown that _he had thought of this,_ however unlikely he deemed it." That's entirely the point. Per Gandalf, Sauron never did, or even could, think of it. From _Fellowship_, Book II, Chapter 2, "The Council of Elrond:" "Into his heart the thought will not enter that any will refuse it, that having the Ring we may seek to destroy it. If we seek this, we shall put him out of reckoning." The plan relied on his _not_ thinking of it, and in the end Gandalf proved to be correct.